# Is it possible to use getters/setters in interface definition?

Tags: interface, get, set, accessor, typescript

At the moment, `TypeScript` does not allow use get/set methods(accessors) in interfaces.
For example:

```
interface I {
      get name(): string;
}

class C implements I {
      get name(): string {
          return null;
      } 
}
```

furthermore, TypeScript does not allow using arrow function expressions in class methods, for example:

```
class C {
    private _name: string;

    get name(): string => this._name;
}
```

Is there any other way I can use a getter and setter on an interface definition?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can specify the property on the interface, but you can't enforce whether getters and setters are used, like this:

```
interface IExample {
    Name: string;
}

class Example implements IExample {
    private _name: string = "Bob";

    public get Name() {
        return this._name;
    }

    public set Name(value) {
        this._name = value;
    }
}

var example = new Example();
alert(example.Name);
```

In this example, the interface doesn't force the class to use getters and setters, I could have used a property instead (example below) - but the interface is supposed to hide these implementation details anyway as it is a promise to the calling code about what it can call.

```
interface IExample {
    Name: string;
}

class Example implements IExample {
    // this satisfies the interface just the same
    public Name: string = "Bob";
}

var example = new Example();
alert(example.Name);
```

And lastly, `=>` is not allowed for class methods - you could [start a discussion on Codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions) if you think there is a burning use case for it. Here is an example:

```
class Test {
    // Yes
    getName = () => 'Steve';

    // No
    getName() => 'Steve';

    // No
    get name() => 'Steve';
}
```

Comment: You can use `=>` for defining class methods like this: `name = (a: string) => this._name;` but in the output JS it will be defined inside the class function rather than extending its prototype object.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with static get properties :/

Answer (score 71):

To supplement the other answers, if your desire is to define a `get value` on an interface, you can use `readonly`:

```
interface Foo {
  readonly value: number;
}

let foo: Foo = { value: 10 };

foo.value = 20; //error

class Bar implements Foo {
  get value() {
    return 10;
  }
}
```

but as far as I'm aware, and as others mentioned, there is no way currently to define a set-only property in the interface. You can, however, move the limitation to a run-time error (useful during the development cycle only):

```
interface Foo {
  /* Set Only! */
  value: number;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  _value:number;
  set value(value: number) {
    this._value = value;
  }
  get value() {
    throw Error("Not Supported Exception");
  }
}
```

**Not recommended practice**; but an option.

Comment: This does feel like the correct answer until `get` and `set` can be declared normally on interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Typescript only supports `get` and `set` syntax when targetting Ecmascript 5. To achieve this, you have to call the compiler with

```
tsc --target ES5
```

Interfaces do not support getters and setters. To get your code to compile you would have to change it to

```
interface I { 
    getName():string;
}

class C implements I { 
    getName():string {
          return null;
    }   
}
```

What typescript does support is a special syntax for fields in constructors. In your case, you could have

```
interface I {
    getName():string;
}

class C implements I {
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }
    getName():string {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Notice how class `C` does not specify the field `name`. It is actually declared using syntactic sugar `public name: string` in the constructor.

As Sohnee points out, the interface is actually supposed to hide any implementation details. In my example, I have chosen the interface to require a java-style getter method. However, you can also a property and then let the class decide how to implement the interface.

Comment: You can use `get` and `set` keywords in TypeScript.

Comment: A side note on ECMAScript 5 support - `Object.defineProperty` is supported in IE8+, FF4+, Opera 12+, WebKit and Safari. There is also an EC5 Shim at https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Answer (score 0):

Using TypeScript 3.4:

```js
interface IPart {
    getQuantity(): number;
}

class Part implements IPart {
    private quantity: number;
    constructor(quantity: number) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public getQuantity = (): number => {
        return this.quantity;
    };
}

let part = new Part(42);

// When used in typescript, quantity is not accessible.
// However, when compiled to javascript it will log '42'.
console.log(part.quantity);

// Logs '42'.
console.log(part.getQuantity());
```

See example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPart%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getQuantity()%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Part%20implements%20IPart%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20quantity%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(quantity%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.quantity%20%3D%20quantity%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getQuantity%20%3D%20()%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.quantity%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20part%20%3D%20new%20Part(42)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20When%20used%20in%20typescript%2C%20quantity%20is%20not%20accessible.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20However%2C%20when%20compiled%20to%20javascript%20it%20will%20log%20'42'.%0D%0Aconsole.log(part.quantity)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Logs%20'42'.%0D%0Aconsole.log(part.getQuantity())%3B).

Comment: per latest typescript version 4.3.2, this answer is correct.

Comment: Not exactly what OP asked but +1 for showing how interface can enforce definition of method in class implementing that interface.