# Is it possible to use a readonly property in TypeScript Interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I would like to define an interface with a readonly property.  For instance (as a strawman);

```
interface foo {
    get bar():bool;
}
```

However, this gives the syntax error, "expected ';'" on bar.  I have setup my VisualStudio to use the ES5 target, so getters are supported.  How would I define a readonly property in an interface?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838248/is-it-possible-to-use-getters-setters-in-interface-definition

Comment: Yes, this is a limitation of interfaces. See also [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838248/is-it-possible-to-use-getters-setters-in-interface-definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use getters/setters in interface definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838248/is-it-possible-to-use-getters-setters-in-interface-definition)

Comment: I'm happy with the accepted answer below.  The link you provide also has good answers.  This accepted answer has a lot of information on how readonly, optional and getters interact https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript/12850536

Comment: This has been marked as a duplicate, but it is not.  The question is about readonly properties in interfaces; the duplicate is specifically about getters/setters in interfaces.  The question uses a getter to implement readonly as a strawman.  However, the accepted answer is much better; readonly  as an attribute.  Look at the accepted answers on the two questions and it you can see it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Getter-only properties were introduced in [Typescript 2.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-properties):

```
interface foo {
    readonly bar: boolean;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this still declares `bar` as a property, not a getter.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov the readonly does not specify that it has to be a property. As properties are referenced in the same ways as getters, the class implementing this interface is free to use a property or a getter.

Comment: @nikeee: Yes, but OP asked if we can use getters/setters in interfaces, not properties.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov but that's exactly what this is, a getter. If you try to assign to the property you get this error `Error TS2540 (TS) Cannot assign to 'bar' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

Comment: Note that this feature only works for *object literals* that implement the interface. (See the `Point` example in the linked article). However, if you try to write a *class* that implements the interface, the `readonly` modifier doesn't apply.

Comment: That's a readonly property not a getter.  There's a slight difference as shown here:  
property:  readonly bar: boolean
getter:  get bar(): boolean { return a && b || c && !e || (x | y | z) }

Comment: You can then write a class like this

    class Bar implements foo {
        get bar (): boolean { return true }
    }

Comment: Does that imply that the class must implement it as readonly, in that case it's not the same contract as stating that a getter is present.

Comment: this is a _partial answer_ but it is not strictly correct. the implementation is free to provide the property either as a typical property or as a computed property (getter). that freedom is valuable in some instances, but insufficiently specific in others. Is there a way to specify that they value must be computed?

Comment: @robertotomás This is not only a partial answer, but the complete, correct answer. The whole reason for having interfaces is to specify contracts that doesn't care about implementation details. If you want to specify implementation details, you use super classes, not interfaces.

Comment: None of that is in the answer, so no it is not complete

Comment: @DennisK, it isn't simply an implementation detail because behavior during a spread operator is different.  In the example above `const x = {...y}` when `y` is a `interface foo` will believe that the type of `x` is `{bar: boolean}`.  But if `y` is actually `class foo { get bar(): boolean }` then it knows that x is `{}`.  There doesn't seem to be a way to tell typescript that you expect a getter unless you construct a whole implementation of it.  If I specify an interface with readonly property and someone gives me a class with a getter, (or vice versa) it breaks but typescript doesn't warn

Comment: @Warren That seems more like a problem with TypeScript's type inference. When it breaks, be specific. In this case, use `y:foo = implementation`.

Comment: @Warren Whoops, you reused the foo name. I'll probably need a larger example to be precise:
```typescript
interface foo {
 readonly bar: boolean;
}

class baz implements foo {
 private _bar = false
 get bar(): boolean {
  return this._bar;
  };
}

const test = () => {
 const y1: foo = {
  bar: true
 };

 const y2:foo = new baz();
 const x1 = {...y1};
 const x2 = {...y2};
 console.log(x1.bar);
 console.log(x2.bar);
};
```

Edit: Argh. Comments on StackOverflow are pretty annoying. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: @Warren Wow, just tried actually running this, and you're right (and I misread your comment). The spread operator only copies concrete properties. My bad.

Comment: I agree that a readonly property is an interface is actually better than a getter in an interface, because you can implement it as you wish.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, this is a limitation of interfaces. Whether or not the access to the property is implemented with a getter is an implementation detail and thus should not be part of the public interface. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838248/is-it-possible-to-use-getters-setters-in-interface-definition).

If you need a readonly attribute specified in an interface, you can add a getter method:

```
interface foo {
    getAttribute() : string;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not an implementation detail that is is read-only.  I wish I could express that in Typescript.

Comment: I see. Then I think your only way is to specify a getter method. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Presumably this will become possible in TypeScript 2.0: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532

Answer (score 6):

As @Vitaliy Ulantikov answered, you may use the `readonly` modifier on a property. This acts exactly like a getter.

```
interface Point {
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;
}
```

When an *object literal* implements the interface, you cannot overwrite a `readonly` property:

```
let p1: Point = { x: 10, y: 20 };
p1.x = 5; // error!
```

But when a *class* implements the interface, there is no way to avoid overwriting it.

```
class PointClassBroken implements Point {
    // these are required in order to implement correctly
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    changeCoordinates(x: number, y: number): void {
        this.x = x // no error!
        this.y = y // no error!
    }
}
```

I guess that’s because when you re-declare properties in the class definition, they override the properties of the interface, and are no longer readonly.

To fix that, use `readonly` on the properties directly in the class that implements the interface

```
class PointClassFixed implements Point {
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    changeCoordinates(x: number, y: number): void {
        this.x = x // error!
        this.y = y // error!
    }
}
```

See for yourself in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20p1%3A%20Point%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%2010%2C%20y%3A%2020%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ap1.x%20%3D%205%3B%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PointClassBroken%20implements%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20these%20are%20required%20in%20order%20to%20implement%20correctly%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20changeCoordinates(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%20%2F%2F%20no%20error!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%20%2F%2F%20no%20error!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PointClassFixed%20implements%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20changeCoordinates(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).